# Would you confirm this as a proof to the Pythagorean theorem?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

I'm new in mathematics, and trying to build my way up starting by doing simple tasks. My current one is proving the Pythagorean theorem without looking it up. This photo contains my current "proof" and I want you to look at it [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huehc.png).

Would this count as a proof? What is it that it lacks if it doesn't? Are there some obvious mistakes in the process of proving a theorem that I did here?

Thank you :)

Comment: You're taking limits, so I think you only proved that $a^2+0^2=a^2$

Comment: Where in the argument do you use the fact that this is a right triangle?  Which line, specifically, is incorrect if the segment of length $b$ isn't perpendicular to the $x$-axis?

Comment: @lulu 

The right triangle is what I used to prove the right column. 
( the left was done using the circle)

looking at the right triangle, as "a" approaches "c", "b" gets smaller and smaller, actually approaching zero. Since it approaches zero, the area of the circle to which "b" is a radius approaches zero as well

Comment: All of those statements would be equally true if $b$ were tilted a bit.  Perhaps more seriously, what does $a\to c$ mean?

Comment: @lulu It means that looking at the right triangle, we know that the hypotenuse's length will remain the same as it is the radius of the big circle. So, if we try to change the length of one of the two remaining sides, the other side will inevitably change as well in order to maintain a right triangle. So, what would happen to the side b if we changed the length of side a and made it closer and closer to the value of the radius? It would definitely get smaller and smaller. In fact, in approaches zero as a approaches the length c.

Comment: But that would also be true if, instead of the right triangle, you drew the segment from the end of $a$ to,say, the point where the circle meets the $x$-axis.  Sorry...I don't think there is much, if any, geometric content in your argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you did: you showed the stuff on the left side was true, and said it implied the right side. But notice the following:
$$\lim_{a \to c}(c^2-a^2)\pi = 0 \implies\lim_{a \to c}b^2 \pi = 0$$
For this to happen, you have to have *assumed* that $c^2-a^2 = b^2$, which is *assuming* what you want to prove (and thus, you don't have a proof due to circular logic).

Comment: But the limit of ((b^2)*(pi)) as "a" approaches "c" is zero because, looking at the right triangle, as "a" approaches "c", "b" gets smaller and smaller, actually approaching zero. Since it approaches zero, the area of the circle to which "b" is a radius approaches zero as well.

So it's not a result of me assuming that (c^2)-(a^2) = (b^2)

Comment: @MahmoudAlawneh You do realize what you're saying makes no sense, right? $a$ and $c$ are the lengths of the triangle - what you are insisting on is a rotation of vectors, which is quite different.

Comment: @MahmoudAlawneh When you are saying $\lim_{a \to c}(c^2 - a^2)$, you are taking the limit as the length $a$ approaches the length $c$. This has nothing to do with moving the vectors, but rather, the lengths. There is no rotation involved.

Comment: Okay, I want to be a little slow with me here. You're probably mentioning some concepts that I'm ignorant of.

In any right triangle, he have a hypotenuse and two sides. In this case, the hypotenuse is a radius of a circle (c). Looking at the circle, as the side (a)'s length gets larger, and therefore getting closer to the circumference of the bigger circle, it's inevitable that b will get smaller and smaller, as the hypotenuse shifts down along the circumference. We're maintaining the same hypotenuse length, but adjusting the lengths of the two other sides.

Comment: Please explain to me why this isn't valid.

Comment: This is a better one:  looking at the right triangle, we know that the hypotenuse's length will remain the same as it is the radius of the big circle. So, if we try to change the length of one of the two remaining sides, the other side will inevitably change as well in order to maintain a right triangle. So, what would happen to the side b if we changed the length of side a and made it closer and closer to the value of the radius? It would definitely get smaller and smaller. In fact, in approaches zero as a approaches the length c. 

Why isn't this valid?